# SIdekiq doesn't perform async (Sinatra & Rack)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, config, rack, sidekiq

I am really newbie to Ruby. I understand the language, but it is really hard for me to get the right way to structure project, there are a lot of articles and tutorials suggest running not with simple `ruby` command but for example `rackup`. I cannot get an idea of using other commands if my app using multiple gems, there are used as a wrappers ?

As for my project. I am creating simple API with `Sinatra` & `Rack & Sidekiq`, I am starting my app as follows.

```
rackup -p1600 --host 192.168.0.130  config.ru
```

But I've just started using `sidekiq` and it required `Redis server` I've installed it, now everything works no errors.

But the problem is that my task is not being processed.

Here is my example

My endpoint

```
  post '/items' do
    item_url = params[:item_url]
    halt(400, {error: 'Item url is not provided'}.to_json) if item_url.nil?
    begin
      item_handler = ItemHandler.new item_url
      item_handler.start_processing
      item_handler.item_status.to_json
    rescue APIErrors::AlreadyExistsError => e
      halt(409, {error: e.message}.to_json)
    rescue APIErrors::InvalidPayloadError => e
      halt(400, {error: e.message}.to_json)
    end
  end
```

And my `ItemHandler`

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = {password: 'password'}
end
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = {password: 'password'}
end

class ItemHandler
...
...
...
  def start_processing
    ItemWorker.perform_async(@item.id)
  end
```

And finnally `ItemWorker`

```
require 'sidekiq'

class ItemWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  attr_accessor :item

  def perform(id)
    # Get item model
    @item = ItemModel.where(_id: id)
    logger.info "Doing hard work"
    puts @item.status
    # Start item processing
    process_item
  end

  def process_item
    logger.info "Doing hard work"
    puts 'Start processing'
    @item.status = ItemModel::STATUS[:downloading]
    @item.save
    result = download_item_file
    if result > RESULT_OK
      @item.status = ItemModel::STATUS[:failed_download]
      @item.save
      puts 'Failed to download file'
    else
      puts 'File downloaded'
      @item.status = ItemModel::STATUS[:downloaded]
      @item.save
    end
  end

  def download_item_file
    return if @item.nil?
    dl_command = EXTERNAL_DOWNLOAD.dup
    dl_command['|url|'] = @item.url
    system dl_command
    $?.exitstatus
  end
end
```

And nothing happens, no output in console, nothing. Previously I've use `fork` instead of `sidekiq` and it worked fine.

Please help me to find the problem.

P.S. If I am doing something other in a wrong way (don't follow best practices & guidelines) please let me know.

Comment: Is it still not working ? everything seems fine, can you sure with us the logs after triggering the function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete example app using `sidekiq/redis` and `sinatra`:

```
~/sinatra_projects$ tree myapp/    
myapp/
├── config.ru
├── item_handler.rb
├── item_worker.rb
└── sinatra_app.rb
```

**sinatra_app.rb**:

```
require 'sinatra'
require_relative 'item_handler' #=>look for item_handler.rb in the same directory as this file

get '/' do
  "hello world"
end

post '/item' do
  puts "--->#{params[:item_url]}<---"

  item_handler = ItemHandler.new params[:item_url]
  item_handler.start_processing

  "Thanks for the work\n"
end
```

**item_handler.rb**:

```
require_relative 'item_worker'  #look for item_worker.rb in the same directory as this file

class ItemHandler
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def start_processing
    ItemWorker.perform_async @url
  end
end
```

**item_worker.rb**:

```
require 'sidekiq'

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  #Not much documentation on what you can/should do in here
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  #Not much documentation on what you can/should do in here
end

class ItemWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(url)
    logger.info "Things are happening"

    case url
    when /joe_blow.com/
      sleep 5
      logger.info "joe_blow.com took a really long time" 
    when /twitter_clone.com/
      sleep 3
      logger.info "twitter_clone.com was pretty slow"
    else /google.com/
      sleep 1
      logger.info "google.com response was the quickest"
    end

  end

end
```

**config.ru**:

```
require_relative 'sinatra_app'  #=>look for sinatra_app.rb in the same directory as this file 

run Sinatra::Application
```

To get things up and running:

1) [Download](https://redis.io) and install redis(not the same as the redis gem), then in terminal_window1 start redis:

```
$ ~/Downloads/redis-3.2.6/src$ ./redis-server
```

2) Install the `sidekiq gem` (which will also install the `redis gem` because it's a dependency):

```
$ gem install sidekiq
```

3) Start sidekiq in terminal_window2:

```
~/sinatra_projects/myproj$ sidekiq -r ./item_worker.rb
```

4) Launch the Sinatra app in terminal_window3:

```
~/sinatra_projects/myproj$ rackup config.ru
```

5) Send a post request to your app in terminal_window4:

```
$ curl --data "item_url=http://joe_blow.com" http://localhost:9292/item
```

Immediately, the curl window will display the output:

```
Thanks for the work
```

and the sidekiq window will display the output:

```
2016-12-28T02:34:59.149Z 12387 TID-oxt2yycrk ItemWorker JID-b9190f121541d82f21483497 INFO: start
2016-12-28T02:34:59.149Z 12387 TID-oxt2yycrk ItemWorker JID-b9190f121541d82f21483497 INFO: Things are happening
```

Five seconds later, the sidekiq window will display:

```
2016-12-28T02:35:04.153Z 12387 TID-oxt2yycrk ItemWorker JID-b9190f121541d82f21483497 INFO: joe_blow.com took a really long time
2016-12-28T02:35:04.154Z 12387 TID-oxt2yycrk ItemWorker JID-b9190f121541d82f21483497 INFO: done: 5.004 sec
```

And if you send three curl requests in rapid succession(up_arrow + Return):

```
$ curl --data "item_url=http://joe_blow.com" http://localhost:9292/item
Thanks for the work
$ curl --data "item_url=http://joe_blow.com" http://localhost:9292/item
Thanks for the work
$ curl --data "item_url=http://joe_blow.com" http://localhost:9292/item
Thanks for the work
```

then in the sideqik window you will see:

```
2016-12-28T02:38:01.218Z 12387 TID-oxt2yycrk ItemWorker JID-3c8db3dc597789eefaf3d7e6 INFO: start
2016-12-28T02:38:01.218Z 12387 TID-oxt2yycrk ItemWorker JID-3c8db3dc597789eefaf3d7e6 INFO: Things are happening
2016-12-28T02:38:01.983Z 12387 TID-oxt319uyc ItemWorker JID-d5a4f4fa5388b2fdb94b8549 INFO: start
2016-12-28T02:38:01.983Z 12387 TID-oxt319uyc ItemWorker JID-d5a4f4fa5388b2fdb94b8549 INFO: Things are happening
2016-12-28T02:38:02.602Z 12387 TID-oxt2y8eec ItemWorker JID-dd8b2ce2e558f5a88a1836fa INFO: start
2016-12-28T02:38:02.602Z 12387 TID-oxt2y8eec ItemWorker JID-dd8b2ce2e558f5a88a1836fa INFO: Things are happening
```

...time goes by...

```
2016-12-28T02:38:06.220Z 12387 TID-oxt2yycrk ItemWorker JID-3c8db3dc597789eefaf3d7e6 INFO: joe_blow.com took a really long time
2016-12-28T02:38:06.220Z 12387 TID-oxt2yycrk ItemWorker JID-3c8db3dc597789eefaf3d7e6 INFO: done: 5.003 sec
2016-12-28T02:38:06.985Z 12387 TID-oxt319uyc ItemWorker JID-d5a4f4fa5388b2fdb94b8549 INFO: joe_blow.com took a really long time
2016-12-28T02:38:06.985Z 12387 TID-oxt319uyc ItemWorker JID-d5a4f4fa5388b2fdb94b8549 INFO: done: 5.002 sec
2016-12-28T02:38:07.603Z 12387 TID-oxt2y8eec ItemWorker JID-dd8b2ce2e558f5a88a1836fa INFO: joe_blow.com took a really long time
2016-12-28T02:38:07.603Z 12387 TID-oxt2y8eec ItemWorker JID-dd8b2ce2e558f5a88a1836fa INFO: done: 5.001 sec
```

Instead of taking a total of 15 seconds to run all three workers, after 5 seconds all three workers finished.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for help, I have just realized one important thing, to make `sidekiq` work, firstly it should be started :))

So I just used this command to start 'sidekiq' and it works fine now.

```
sidekiq -r ./item_downloader.rb
```

My bad

Comment: Thanks for posting that.  I created a simpler app from your example, and I could not see any log messages either.  I've been banging my head against a wall for a day.  It's not clear from your post what file you are supposed to specify in the `sidekiq` command--I specified the file which contains the class that has the line `include Sidekiq:Worker` inside it, e.g. item_worker.rb. Then in the terminal window where I issued the sideqik command (v. the window where I issued the rackup command or the window where I started redis), I could see the logged messages.